# Flutter: The backdrop filter's blur effect is pushed back in the stack when scrolling the listview?

Tags: flutter

I'm not a professional programmer, but I'm having the problem of the blur effect disappearing or being overwritten when scrolling to the beginning of the list or the end of the list.

```
return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          width: 100,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 100,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  child: BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 20, sigmaY: 20),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },

    );
```

After scrolling to the beginning of the list or the end of the list, it produces unexpected results like the image I provided
https://www.figma.com/file/FR2N0ZGTGiQEvgK7sw59cD/Untitled?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=gxwYPWr1AKmQzYNQ-1
(I can't display images, because I'm new, this website doesn't allow me to embed images, sorry for the inconvenience)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: can you update the image you want to achieve? the link is invalid

Comment: images not openining. and where did you test it: android/ios, simulator/real/device?

Comment: I can't display the image, because I'm new, this website doesn't allow me to embed images